# Calculating distance between two places on Google Maps in RoR app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-4

I am creating a rails application for a taxi booking platform that requires entering a pickup point and a drop point. I have included the following script in my application.html.erb for this purpose within the header tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var placeSearch,autocomplete;
  function initialize() {
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('autocomplete'));
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
      fillInAddress();
    });

    autocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('autocomplete2'));
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete2, 'place_changed', function() {
      fillInAddress();
});
  }
  function fillInAddress() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    for (var component in component_form) {
      document.getElementById(component).value = "";
      document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < place.address_components.length; j++) {
      var att = place.address_components[j].types[0];
      if (component_form[att]) {
        var val = place.address_components[j][component_form[att]];
        document.getElementById(att).value = val;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

I have then used this js as follows in my  tag:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= label_tag ("Pickup Location: ") %><br>
    <%= text_field_tag :pickup_loc, nil, :id => "autocomplete", :placeholder => "Enter your pickup location" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag ("Drop Location: ") %><br>
    <%= text_field_tag :drop_loc, nil, :id => "autocomplete2", :placeholder => "Enter your dropoff location" %>
  </div>
```

This works perfectly. Now I want to calculate the distance between my pickup and drop locations. I am using `GoogleDirections.new(params[:pickloc], params[:droploc]).distance_in_miles` for this purpose (`https://github.com/joshcrews/google-directions-ruby`). This works in some cases, but in other cases, this return 0. Seems Google can’t recognize my places. How do I rectify? Please be descriptive in your answer as I am new to both rails and JS. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This link [GoogleDirections#distance_in_miles](https://github.com/joshcrews/google-directions-ruby/blob/master/lib/google_directions.rb#L66), shows that the method `distance_in_miles` returns `0` if `@status` is not `OK`.  Have you verified that your requests are successful when you get `0`?

Comment: Correct...the status shows “NOT_FOUND”, which means that for some of these cases, where the distance is 0, GoogleDirections doesn't identify these places on the maps. What could be the reason and possible workaround?